# Get at the Office 2007 setup program

Tags: microsoft-office

I need to check that my install of Office 2007 has SharePoint support enabled. But Microsoft Office is not showing up in the Add/Remove programs control panel (I'm on XP). Is there another way of running the setup program so I can get at the "add/remove features" part of Office setup?

Comment: OK, this was me being really stupid. I was looking for "Microsoft Office Suite" and I should have been looking for "Microsoft Office Enterprise". Running repair made Sharepoint office integration work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run it from the install CD

Comment: I assume he doesn't have that ;-) Might be an enterprise computer

Comment: Then he may have himself a slight problem :)

Comment: You could probably download the microsoft office trial and run it's setup routine although there is a possibility of it going horribly wrong.